# How to enable Microsoft Symbol Server in OlyDbg?

Tags: debugging, symbols, ollydbg, dbghelp

[OlyDbg version 2](http://www.ollydbg.de/version2.html) was recently released. It now supports using the Microsoft Symbol Server for debugging:

> It supports Microsoft compilers via dbghelp.dll. New is support for symbol server, stack walking using dbghelp and names of procedure parameters.

How do i make OlyDbg use Microsoft Symbol Server?

## What have you tried?

[image]

**Long answer:**

- i've pointed OlyDbg to the folder that will contain symbols after DbgHelp.dll downloads them
- i've told OlyDbg that it's okay to access the Microsoft Symbol Server
- i've told OlyDbg that it's okay to use DbgHelp.dll
- i've tried updating the version of DbgHelp.dll that OlyDbg 2.0 ships with (2008) to the version that ships with the Windows 8 SDK
- i've set a system environment variable:

  ```
  _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=SRV*d:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
  ```
- i've added `SRV*d:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` as a *"directory"* that OlyDbg should search, ala the YouTube video

  [image]

### What makes you think it's not working?

- a) The symbol directory is empty
- b) There is no internet traffic to msdl.microsoft.com
- c) No symbols appear in OlyDbg 2.0

  [image]

### See also

- [How to use OS symbol files in OllyDbg?](http://www.woodmann.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-11946.html) (OlyDbg v1; the guy who knew refused to answer because he was grumpy)
- [How to use OS symbol pdb files in OllyDbg?](http://www.openrce.org/forums/posts/187) (OlyDbg v1)
- [YouTube: HowTo: Using OllyDbg v2.1d and v2.1.0.4 with MS debug symbols server](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aleqOPqPdeQ) (*Warning: mute audio*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When starting ollydbg with the options you configured, you should have gotten a message in the "Log data" child window saying: `Missing SYMSRV.DLL, Microsoft Symbol Server is deactivated`.

The file that downloads the symbols from microsoft servers is called `symsrv.dll`. I don't think microsoft provides a single download for only that file. However, it is included in various microsoft developer packs:

- microsoft windows sdk
- microsoft windows driver kit
- microsoft debug-tools (now in windows driver kit?)

Just download and install any of these and search the folder for `symsrv.dll`. Be careful not to get the x64 variant as it has the same name. Copy this file to the ollydbg directory and everything should work.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. That was on Windows 8, which i'd since abandoned. There is no such entry in the log, and while symbols now (on Windows 7?) do load from the web-site: Olly doesn't display them. Perhaps i simply had expectations too high; i thought i would see parameter names.